# Search for a library in software center

Tags: software-installation, libraries

I search a library called  pango in 12.04 software center, but it returns nothing.

But if I search for  libpango, it will returns  libpango1.0-dev.

I wonder how to search for a library in a correct way in the software center?

What if in command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for a library:

```
apt-cache search library-name-here
```

Obtain the source code:

```
sudo apt-get source library-or-program-name-here
```